# RegionPlot of annulus gives a mesh

Tags: graphics, regions

So I tried plotting an annulus in two ways:

```
RegionPlot[Annulus[{0,0},{a,b}]]
Graphics[Annulus[{0,0},{a,b}]]
```

Why does RegionPlot give a fractal looking thing? (see below for when a=1; b=5;)
[image: RegionPlot image]

*note, I used wolfram programing lab.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ here?

Comment: Try a=1; b=5;
But really any values give something weird

Comment: Because it discretized the region in order to plot it, and it is showing the underlying triangulation mesh.

Comment: Your picture looks better than mine.  I am using *Mathematica*.  What is "Wolfram Language"?  Is that *Mathematica* or *Wolfram Alpha* (or both)?

Comment: @mjw it is cloud mathematica https://develop.wolframcloud.com/app/

Comment: @MarcoB Why doesn't Region also give fractal like thing?

Comment: @IonSme I guess they just use different defaults for plotting; the Graphics result is "normal-looking" though.

Comment: Explicit lines are returned in the plot and we can remove them manually with `RegionPlot[Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 5}]] /. _Line -> {}`.

Comment: There are some subtle differences going on how Mma shows `Region`s and `RegionPlot` `Graphics`. Also `Region`s can be defined analytically via `ImplicitRegion` or `ParametricRegion` or as 'flat' `MeshRegion`s. `DiscretizeRegion` converts every type to a `MeshRegion` and some functions like `RegionPlot` might use something similar to `DiscretizeRegion` under the hood to make plotting easier, whose discretization it for some reason decides to show. Like others wrote you can use `ImplicitRegion` to get a different (not discretized) look in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 a = 1; b = 5;
```

Please try plotting with `Region[]`.  These look okay to me:

```
 Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, b], Disk[{0, 0}, a]]]
```

[image]

```
 Region[Annulus[{0, 0}, {a, b}]]
```

[image]

Here is a decent plot, with `RegionPlot`:

```
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 > 1 && x^2 + y^2 < 25, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}]
```

[image]

Here it is (again) with `Graphics[]`:

```
 Graphics[{LightBlue, Annulus[{0, 0}, {a, b}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, that worked, but why is RegionPlot so funky?

Comment: I think MarcoB mostly answers this below your question.  So we can then ask:  Why does `RegionPlot` use one algorithm, and `Region` another?  `RegionPlot` seems to like functions as inputs, and also likes to have the $x$ and $y$ ranges speciifed ...